# Yellow warning triangle in Xcode 9's Create Bot.. window

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode9, macos-high-sierra, xcode-server

I'm trying to set up continuous integration (CI) in Xcode 9 with it's new built-in Xcode Server functionality. (MacBook Pro, macOS High Sierra)

I've been following various tutorials, such as [Tutorial: Continuous Integration with Xcode 9 and FastLane](https://medium.com/@evertoncunha/tutorial-continuous-integration-with-xcode-9-and-fastlane-b0c5d605b233), [Xcode Server and Continuous Integration Guide: Configure Bots to Perform Continuous Integration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots.html), and a few others.

Everything seems to work fine, till I get to the Product -> Create Bot... step. The window opens with a yellow triangle/exclamation mark warning symbol to the right of the Server dropdown:

[image: Create Bot... window]

The Previous and Next buttons are disabled. Nothing happens if I click on the warning triangle, and there are no other related messages I can see in Xcode or the macOS console.

I performed the same setup on another MacBook Pro running High Sierra and the same version of Xcode 9. There was no triangle on that one, and I was able to select Next and continue the process.

Update: The triangle is present for any project I create. And, I've tried closing/restarting both Xcode and the MacBook Pro.

I've searched repeatedly for things like *create bot yellow triangle*, *create bot warning symbol*, *xcode 9 continuous integration warning symbol*, etc, but found nothing relevant.

Has anybody seen this, and what does it mean/how do I fix it???

Comment: restart the Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the actual problem was that, in Accounts, I used the integration user I had set up. That was incorrect. I needed to put myself or another *registered user* into the Account section.

Once I added my own user's Name and Password into the Accounts/Xcode Server section, I was able to successfully create a bot.

Answer (score 0):

Your Server & Bots option in Xcode Preferences is still not enabled even though you did it earlier.
Re-enable it and this should fix the issue.
[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Qn4.png)

Also make sure permissions are set correctly, [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMgGh.png)

Comment: Okayyyyy.... I did this a whole bunch of times before posting my question, and it never worked. I haven't touched it again 'til now, and this time it worked perfectly. Weirdness - but thanks!

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. I followed the steps you showed, as I had done before, and that worked, so I got excited and checked your answer. However, I didn't go far enough: I still couldn't actually create a bot until I changed the account information.